# In "mysql -u username -p -A" command what does 'A' stands for?

Tags: mysql

In `mysql -u username  -p  -A` command what does `A` stands for ?

Whenever I try to login mysql database if I change that `A` to small letter(a) then this will not allow me to log in.

Comment: You've tried changing two variables at once: removing `-A`, and adding `-a`. Have you tried removing `-A` without adding `-a`? Adding `-a` without removing `-A`? If so -- what did you find?

Comment: @Shree [**don't forget to mark the right answer, click here to see how**](http://stackoverflow.com/about)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-A` enables tab-completion of table-names etc. However it is enabled by default so you can omit it entirely.

In the command line, everything is case-sensitive, so `-A` and `-a` mean entirely different things. `-a` isn't even an option for MySQL.

Just omit the `-A` entirely.

In the future you can use the `man` (short for `manual`) tool to find out about any command line program: `man mysql`.

Comment: No problem :) make sure to mark an answer as accepted by clicking the tickbox on the left of any answer.